# SqlNode is not connected in MySQL NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, sql-server, centos, centos7, mysql-cluster

I am trying to connect my sql node, management node and 1 data node in mysql cluster but when I try `ndb_mgm` in management node then this output will display

```
Cluster Configuration
    ---------------------
    [ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
    id=2     @10.0.40.105    (mysql-5.5.25 ndb-7.2.7, Nodegroup: 0, Master)

    [ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
    id=1     @10.0.40.119    (mysql-5.5.25 ndb-7.2.7)

    [mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
    id=3 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)
```

mysqld is not connected but accepting connection from host

my config.ini and my.cnf file is correct 
I think port number is having some issue
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest version 8.0.19. Mine has the same issue.

Data node is fine. But somehow sql node cann't be connected...

I am using the latest version 8.0.19 bundle on CentOS 8..

Comment: Can't fix the problem.

Comment: check for the logs and include pid-file location in my.cnf file it will resolve the error